# Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Biology Stack Exchange](http://biology.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [By what mechanism is Streptococcus bovis acting as a risk factor for colorectal cancer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8396/by-what-mechanism-is-streptococcus-bovis-acting-as-a-risk-factor-for-colorectal)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What is the best way to clean plastic flasks that have been used for cell cultures - is virkon a good idea?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8574/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-plastic-flasks-that-have-been-used-for-cell-cultur)

  **Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 9)
- [Intracellular lipid transport](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8672/intracellular-lipid-transport)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Meat and mushroom allergies, why are they so rare?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8566/meat-and-mushroom-allergies-why-are-they-so-rare)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Prenatal Marketing](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8667/prenatal-marketing)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Deep diving in mammals](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8782/deep-diving-in-mammals)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Immunity during pregnancy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8432/immunity-during-pregnancy)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [How do changes in temperature affect body weight in humans?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/how-do-changes-in-temperature-affect-body-weight-in-humans)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Why does oxygen bind to hemoglobin in an specific angle?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8611/why-does-oxygen-bind-to-hemoglobin-in-an-specific-angle)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is there a DNA test to identify dog mixes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8731/is-there-a-dna-test-to-identify-dog-mixes)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)